# Can I add color to bootstrap icons only using CSS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sprite, css-sprites

[Twitter's bootstrap uses Icons by Glyphicons](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons). They are "`available in dark gray and white`" by default:

[image: Picture-58.png]

Is it possible to use some CSS trickery to change the colors of the icons? I was hoping for some other css3 brilliance that would prevent having to have an icon image set for each color.

I know you can change the background color of the enclosing (`<i>`) element, but I'm talking about the icon foreground color. I guess it would be possible to inverse the transparency on the icon image and then set the background color.

So, can I add color to bootstrap icons only using CSS?

Comment: I don't think so... But you could probably do that with javascript and a canvas element.

Comment: @bfavaretto - can you elaborate? do you mean coming up with code / coordinates to draw each of the icons or using the existing png image somehow?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not experienced enough with the canvas element to suggest you code, but I know you can manipulate the pixels individually with a canvas.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

Yes, if you use [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/) with Bootstrap! The icons are slightly different, but there are more of them, they look great at any size, and you can change the colors of them.

Basically the icons are fonts and you can change the color of them just with the CSS color property. Integration instructions are at the bottom of the page in the provided link.

---

**Edit:** Bootstrap 3.0.0 icons are now fonts!

As some other people have also mentioned with the release of Bootstrap 3.0.0, the default [icon glyphs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons) are now fonts like Font Awesome, and the color can be changed simply by changing the `color` CSS property. Changing the size can be done via `font-size` property.

Comment: Ahh, clever! Don't forget to set `cursor: default;` so users don't see the I-Bar. Also, check out FF Chartwell, a really clever font: http://tktype.com/chartwell.php

Comment: When you mouse-over text (like in a word processor) your cursor looks like an oversized capital "`I`" character, it's used for selecting text. In CSS it's referred to as `cursor: text;`. It's also known as "I-beam".

Comment: @hajpoj the `Font Awesome` link is broken.

Answer (score 40):

With the latest release of Bootstrap RC 3, changing the color of the icons is as simple as adding a class with the color you want and adding it to the span.

Default black color:

```
<h1>Password Changed <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></h1>
```

would become

```
<h1>Password Changed <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon-success"></span></h1>
```

CSS

```
.icon-success {
    color: #5CB85C;
}
```

[Bootstrap 3 Glyphicons List](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons)

Answer (score 18):

Because the glyphicons are now fonts, one can use the [contextual classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes) to apply the appropriate color to the icons.

For example:
`<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign text-info"></span>`
adding `text-info` to the css will make the icon the info blue color.

Comment: Thanks was looking for a way to apply the contextual classes.  Any of the text-* contextual classes will work

Answer (score 14):

Another possible way to have bootstrap icons in a different color is to create a new .png in the desired color, (eg. magenta) and save it as /path-to-bootstrap-css/img/glyphicons-halflings-**magenta**.png

In your **variables.less** find

```
// Sprite icons path
// -------------------------
@iconSpritePath:          "../img/glyphicons-halflings.png";
@iconWhiteSpritePath:     "../img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png";
```

and add this line

```
@iconMagentaSpritePath:     "../img/glyphicons-halflings-magenta.png";
```

In your **sprites.less** add

```
/* Magenta icons with optional class, or on hover/active states of certain elements */
.icon-magenta,
.nav-pills > .active > a > [class^="icon-"],
.nav-pills > .active > a > [class*=" icon-"],
.nav-list > .active > a > [class^="icon-"],
.nav-list > .active > a > [class*=" icon-"],
.navbar-inverse .nav > .active > a > [class^="icon-"],
.navbar-inverse .nav > .active > a > [class*=" icon-"],
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover > [class^="icon-"],
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover > [class*=" icon-"],
.dropdown-menu > .active > a > [class^="icon-"],
.dropdown-menu > .active > a > [class*=" icon-"],
.dropdown-submenu:hover > a > [class^="icon-"],
.dropdown-submenu:hover > a > [class*=" icon-"] {
  background-image: url("@{iconMagentaSpritePath}");
}
```

And use it like this:

```
<i class='icon-chevron-down icon-magenta'></i>
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: just wanted to reiterate `I was hoping for some other css3 brilliance that would prevent having to have an icon image set for each color`

Comment: Can't be done purely via CSS that is cross browser compatible too. Usually people need a color scheme with related icons - so I would say upto 5 color sets isn't that much of a challenge.

Comment: @seppludger How do you create a new color halfling sprite? Have you succeeded in doing this? I cannot change colors if I load them in any graphics editor.

Answer (score 7):

Quick and dirty work around which did it for me, not actually coloring the icon, but surrounding it with a label or badge in the color you want;

```
<span class="label-important label"><i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i></span>
<span class="label-success label"><i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i></span>
```

Comment: Your answer was useful,+1.I wanted to use edit icon and want to put yellow color. Can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Well you could just change the icon-ok to something else; e.g. <span class="label-warning label"><i class="icon-<iconname> icon-white"></i></span>. For example: <span class="label-warning label"><i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i></span>. It is better to go for the new bootstrap imo..

Answer (score 6):

The Bootstrap Glyphicons are fonts. This means it can be changed like any other text through CSS styling.

CSS:

```
<style>
   .glyphicon-plus {
       color: #F00; 
   }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
```

Example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Glyphicon Colors</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
   .glyphicon-plus {
        color: #F00;    
   }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Watch the course [Up and Running with Bootstrap 3](http://goo.gl/HcDQkY) by Jen Kramer, or watch the individual lesson on [Overriding core CSS with custom styles](http://goo.gl/OY27hW).

Answer (score 4):

It is actually very easy:

just use:

```
.icon-name{
color: #0C0;}
```

For example:

```
.icon-compass{
color: #C30;}
```

That's it.

Answer (score 4):

This is all a bit roundabout..

I've used the glyphs like this

```
  </div>
        <div class="span2">
            <span class="glyphicons thumbs_up"><i class="green"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="span2">
            <span class="glyphicons thumbs_down"><i class="red"></i></span>
        </div>
```

and to affect the color, i included a bit of css at the head like this

```
<style>
        i.green:before {
            color: green;
        }
        i.red:before {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
```

Voila, green and red thumbs.

Answer (score 4):

Also works with the style tag:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" style="color:#00FF00;"></span>

<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="color:#FF0000;"></span>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use the `mask-image` property, but it's a bit of a hack. It's demonstrated in the Safari blog [here](http://www.webkit.org/blog/181/css-masks/).

It's also described in-depth [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/Masks/Masks.html).

Basically you'd create a CSS box, with say a `background-image: gradient(foo);` and then apply an image mask to it based on those PNG images.

It would save you development time making individual images in Photoshop, but I don't think it would save much bandwidth unless you'll be displaying the images in a wide variety of colours. Personally I wouldn't use it because you need to adjust your markup to use the technique effectively, but I'm a member of the "purity is imperitive" school-of-thought.

Comment: Keep in mind support for the `mask-image` property [isn't that great](http://caniuse.com/css-masks).

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [GLYPHICONS](http://glyphicons.com/) and you will be able to change color just setting the CSS:

```
#myglyphcustom {
    color:#F00;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer (using font awesome) is the right one. But since I just wanted the red variant to show on validation errors, I ended using an addon package, kindly offered [on this site](http://www.devlifeline.com/2013/09/twitter-bootstrap-glyphicons-extended.html).

Just edited the url paths in css files since they are absolute (start with /) and I prefer to be relative. Like this:

```
.icon-red {background-image: url("../img/glyphicons-halflings-red.png") !important;}
.icon-purple {background-image: url("../img/glyphicons-halflings-purple.png") !important;}
.icon-blue {background-image: url("../img/glyphicons-halflings-blue.png") !important;}
.icon-lightblue {background-image: url("../img/glyphicons-halflings-lightblue.png") !important;}
.icon-green {background-image: url("../img/glyphicons-halflings-green.png") !important;}
.icon-yellow {background-image: url("../img/glyphicons-halflings-yellow.png") !important;}
.icon-orange {background-image: url("../img/glyphicons-halflings-orange.png") !important;}
```

Comment: Finally, the one compatible with the old versions of Bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

You can change color globally as well

i.e.

```
 .glyphicon {
       color: #008cba; 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought that I might add this snippet to this old post.
This is what I had done in the past, before the icons were fonts:

```
<i class="social-icon linkedin small" style="border-radius:7.5px;height:15px;width:15px;background-color:white;></i>
<i class="social-icon facebook small" style="border-radius:7.5px;height:15px;width:15px;background-color:white;></i>
```

This is very similar to @frbl 's sneaky answer, yet it does not use another image. Instead, this sets the background-color of the `<i>` element to `white` and uses the CSS property `border-radius` to make the entire `<i>` element "rounded." If you noticed, the value of the `border-radius` (7.5px) is exactly half that of the `width` and `height` property (both 15px, making the icon square), making the `<i>` element circular.