# Icon Fonts: How do they get rendered by web pages?

Tags: css, fonts, icons, icon-fonts

I understand that icon fonts are just fonts and that you can get the icons by just calling their classname, but ***how*** do icon fonts work?

I've tried checking the related icon font resources loaded in Chrome to see how icon fonts display icons (in comparison to general fonts) but I haven't been able to figure out how this happens.

I've also been unsuccessful in finding resources on how this "icon font technique" is done, even though there are loads of [**icon fonts available**](http://thenextweb.com/dd/2012/10/12/7-gorgeous-icon-fonts-to-speed-up-your-site-and-your-design-process/). There are also loads of resources showing how icon fonts can be  [**integrated**](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/#integration), but no one seems to be sharing or writing about ***how*** this is done!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

[Glyphicons](http://glyphicons.com/) are [images](http://glyphicons.com/wp-content/themes/glyphicons/images/glyphicons_halflings.png) and *not* a font. All the icons are found within a sprite image (also available as individual images) and they are added to the elements as positioned `backround-image`s:

[image: Glyphicons]

Actual font icons ([FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/), for instance) *do* involve downloading a specific font and make use of the `content` property, for instance:

```
@font-face {
    ...
    src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.0.1') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.0.1') format('woff'),
         url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.0.1') format('truetype');
    ...
}

.icon-beer:before {
    content: "\f0fc";
}
```

As the `content` property [isn't supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=content) in older browsers, these *also* make use of [images](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/assets/img/glyphicons-halflings.png).

Here's an example of completely raw FontAwesome in use as a font, turning `&#xf0f9;` ( - you may not be able to see this!) into an ambulance: http://jsfiddle.net/GWqcF/2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379153/can-i-add-color-to-bootstrap-icons-only-using-css  - the answer says - its basically fonts

Comment: FontAwesome icons **are** fonts. I've even mentioned FontAwesome in my answer and gone on to say how they handle browsers which do not support their CSS method of adding the icons to the page.

Comment: Then how does font icons work ? - how can font be rendered as icons ? - with font icons - are the sprites downloaded ?

Comment: The icons are the font's characters. As a crude example: the letter "Z" could be designed to look like a suitcase, saved as a font and then used on a website.

Comment: Sorry that i changed the question -  I was under the impression that font icons and Glyphicons are the same. I know how sprites work. Wanted to know how font icons worked.

Comment: So you're telling that all the icons are really just distorted characters?

Comment: Here's an example of completely raw FontAwesome in use, turning `&#xf0f9;` into an ambulance: http://jsfiddle.net/GWqcF/2

Comment: @VivekChandra yes that's right! :-) Icon fonts are just like any other font except that the characters are styled to look like icons. FontAwesome uses a range of [characters reserved for "private use"](http://www.unicodemap.org/range/78/Private_Use/).

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for all the resources - will look into it, things are more clearer now.

Comment: My Browser does only load little Boxes with e.g. `F0F9` inside of it. Why?

Comment: @EdwardBlack did you remember the `\` character? Have you loaded  Font-Awesome correctly?

Comment: I opened the jsfiddle from you, and only little boxes are loaded

Comment: @JamesDonnelly, Can you explain how material icons work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45323577/how-md-icons-are-rendered-on-browser

Comment: Urls in this jsfiddle are out of date, just replace them with actual (e.g. `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot` and so for `.woff` and `.ttf`), you'll see image in the second string.

Comment: Does fontawesome download all the fonts upfront?

Answer (score 27):

If your question is how a CSS class can insert a specific character (that will be rendered as an icon in the special font), take a look at the [source for FontAwesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/731953d9efa9e83a8f13d296de605057d0fb366d/web-fonts-with-css/css/fontawesome-all.css#L1756):

```
.icon-glass:before { content: "\f000"; }
.icon-music:before { content: "\f001"; }
.icon-search:before { content: "\f002"; }
.icon-envelope:before { content: "\f003"; }
.icon-heart:before { content: "\f004"; }
```

So a CSS content directive is used to insert the character (which is from a special private-use reserved area of Unicode that does not mess up other readers).

Comment: What does the slash f mean?

Comment: The `f` is not part of it, it's just the hex number 15. The backslash starts the escape sequence for a hexadecimal codepoint. `\f004` in CSS is like `&#xf004;` in HTML.

Answer (score 13):

**How webfont icons work?**

Web-fonts icons work by using CSS to inject a specific glyph into the HTML using the content property. It then uses `@font-face` to load a dingbat webfont that styles the injected glyph. The upshot is that that injected glyph becomes the desired icon.

To begin, you’ll need a web-font file with the icons you need, either defined for particular `ASCII` characters `(A, B, C, !, @, #, etc.)` or in the Private Use Area of the Unicode font, which are spaces in the font that will not be used by specific characters in a Unicode encoded font.

**Read more, how to create webfont icon at [Responsive Webfont Icons](http://webstandardssherpa.com/reviews/responsive-webfont-icons/?utm_source=buffer&utm_campaign=Buffer&utm_content=buffereac5b&utm_medium=google).**

Answer (score 1):

The most popular answer says that Font Awesome uses images. From what I understood, it does not use images in the normal case.

Let's do some experiments to dive into details.

I used the following minimal code to test Font Awesome.
You can try it yourself. Copy-paste it into a static HTML file and open the file in a browser.

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css"> 
  </head>
  
  

  <body>
  
      <i class="fas fa-desktop" ></i>
      <i class="fas fa-desktop" style="color:red"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-desktop" style="color:blue;font-style:italic"></i>
       <i class="fas fa-desktop" style="color:green;font-style:italic;font-size:40px"></i>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I have used a Font Awesome desktop icon with style applied on top of it using the simple `style=""` attribute.
Here is the result..

[image]

It responds to everything that a font can respond to. It responds to color, It responds to italics, and it responds to font size.

So to me, it does not look like a static image. Maybe it is SVG?
Open Chrome network tab and refresh to load the static HTML file again.
I see only these calls:

[image]

There is one font file: fa-solid-900.woff2 ([web open font format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/WOFF)). Download this file just for the experiment and put it within the same folder as our experimental HTML file, we will refer to it in next experiment.

Let's create a new HTML file without refering to Font Awesome CSS and just using the font file:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>   
    
    
    <style>
    
    @font-face {
        font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 900;
        font-display: block;
        src: url(fa-solid-900.woff2)
    }
    
    .my-custom-desktop-icon:before 
    {
      font-weight: 900;
      font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
      content: "\f108";
    }
    
    </style>
    
  </head>
  
  

  <body>
  Custom Icon classes
  
      <span class="my-custom-desktop-icon" ></span>
      <i class="my-custom-desktop-icon" style="color:red"></i>
      <i class="my-custom-desktop-icon" style="color:blue;font-style:italic"></i>
       <i class="my-custom-desktop-icon" style="color:green;font-style:italic;font-size:40px"></i>

</body>
</html>
```

Result is the same:

[image]

I do not understand the full details of font creation yet. However, this is a high-level understanding. For each font icon class Font Awesome has specified a special font shape which it accesses by using a special character sequence. For desktop icon it is \f108

Font Awesome uses CSS classes with the selector `:before` for linking each font shape with a class name. Like the following...

```
.my-custom-desktop-icon:before 
        {
          font-weight: 900;
          font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
          content: "\f108";
        }
```

If we look at the Font Awesome CSS file there are references to many other src for a font but I think the browser loads the first compatible file only. So for most browsers, image files are not required.