# CSS image content: '\f035';

Tags: css, image, github, css-content, octicons

I was just looking through the source of github.com's page and I saw them use some code for their add to clipboard button icon

```
.octicon-clippy:before {
      content: '\f035';
}
```

How can this create an icon without a path to an image?

Comment: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/, http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are familiar with font-awesome, but it too uses unicode characters to create icons. [Check this out](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/).

After you save the font-awesome stylesheets...etc. to your project you can insert an image icon as simple as:

```
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>
```

**EDIT**

You mentioned a clipboard icon, well here is how simple it would be with font-awesome:

```
<i class="fa fa-clipboard"></i>
```

[source](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/clipboard/)

Answer (score 1):

`f035` is an [escape sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence) and is rendered as a single character. My guess is they use [icon font technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503139/font-icons-how-does-it-work).