# How to display Unicode character in bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, unicode

I have this code

```
.progress-button .content::before {
    content: "\e601";
}

.progress-button .content::after {
   content: "\e601";
}
```

It basically returns the value of `"\e601"` into a check mark and `"\e600"` into a `X` sign, the code works well in normal HTML/CSS but when I implemented it into Bootstrap 3, it shows a square sign instead. Can someone please shed me some lights? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You have to include font-awesome related font files

Comment: Include `font-family` and then `content`

Comment: I tried using glyphicon by putting it exactly after content: but also it didn't work

Comment: I have linked it to font-awesome in header, and also the respective font-family , still no result friends :(

Comment: Could you please share the code?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: hey guys, it worked, yeah the advised solutions worked. I mistakenly put the font into wrong folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to add the below line in your head tag and define the font-family wherever you use these unicode characters in your custom css file. Then only will you be able to see the desired icon.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503139/icon-fonts-how-do-they-work) for more details.