# What technique used to make css content into icon?

Tags: css, fonts, icons

Often we can see CSS coding practices that use pseudo class such as **before** or **after** along with **content** inside it to eventually make it become an icon. such as

```
.email:before {content: '\e600'; font-family: special-font}
```

I think this question could be more relevant to how font-family works to render icon. Any idea on how does this works are welcome or point me some directions that I can do more research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help?

[Icon Fonts: How do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503139/icon-fonts-how-do-they-work)

Basically, the content code maps to a point in the font. The font is actually an icon. That css is a way to place the icon in the content without actually specifying it in the html content.

Full explanation here: https://webstandardssherpa.com/reviews/responsive-webfont-icons/?utm_source=buffer&utm_campaign=Buffer&utm_content=buffereac5b&utm_medium=google