# Why setting font-family for whole document breaks fa icons?

Tags: css

I wanted to set the font-family for the whole document. I read that setting it to a body element excludes elements that don't inherit font styles (like form).

So i tried to use this:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

But it breaks the font awesome icons:

[icons not visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzu1y.png)

But if set the font-family like this, it works:

```
* {
  font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

Can you please tell me, what is the problem with the first code?
Thank you!

Comment: Aren't **Font** Awesome icons part of a **font** that you override?

Comment: Read [Icon Fonts: How do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15503139/215552)