# Markers as icons with dynamic color in Openlayers

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, openlayers

I have a code that creates dynamic markers on Openlayers dynamically through php:

```
$shapeStyle="\"$shapeName\":{\"graphicName\": \"triangle\",fillColor:\"$color\",pointRadius:$size,label:\"$label\",labelYOffset:7+$size}"
```

Now I want to upgrade this method and do the same thing with icons, instead of being restricted to the few options which Openlayer provides: “circle”, “square”, “star”, “x”, “cross” and “triangle”.

I know it can be done with OpenLayers.Marker, but since I will have N colour types, the operation of colouring N times the set of M icons seems too expensive to me. And not too flexible either.

I wonder if I can play with imageDiv (OpenLayers.Icon.imageDiv) so I can add some html that inserts bootstrap's Font Awesome's icons. This icons can be coloured through css, as explained in this post: " [Can I add color to bootstrap icons only using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379153/can-i-add-color-to-bootstrap-icons-only-using-css) ".

Is there any hope for this alternative method?

Comment: "I know it can be done with OpenLayers.Marker". Actually, you can't you need to use vector features with and `externalGraphic` like @xamamano says.

Comment: When I was saying that I could do it through OpenLayers.Marker I was thinking about having each png colored separately, and then selecting them as either /red/myIcon.png, or /blue/myIcon.png, etc: 

`var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('/$selectedColor/myIcon.png',size,offset);
markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(new OpenLayers.LonLat(0,0),icon));`

This would be the "brute force" way for me...

Comment: were you able to solve this finally? I am looking to use fontawesome in markers for openlayers too..

Comment: No, sorry... what I did instead was to use my own custom vectorial drawings which onpenlayers (which was slow as hell, but in the end it became my only option). Like this: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/graphic-name.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do this if you keep using vectorial features and styles. Use `"externalGraphic"` with `"graphicWidth"` and `"graphicHeight"`

See the options available at:

http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Feature/Vector-js.html#OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.OpenLayers.Feature.Vector

Comment: The documentation says: "externalGraphic: {String} Url to an external graphic that will be used for rendering points.". And all the examples I have seen use a .png in the Url... so if I am linking to an image, I would not be able to change the color of this image. This is why I wanted to use bootstrap icons, which are able to do so. Unless I am mistaken and I can somehow use a div as externalGraphic...

Comment: You can use vector shapes as external graphics.

Comment: That seems promising. So, my guess is: if I insert something like `externalGraphic: "\path_to\myIcon.svg"`, then I will be able to set `fillColor:#FF0000` to the corresponding openlayers' shape style and this will make it become red?

Comment: I don't know an option as well. 
Only work with substitutions `externalGraphic: "${myUrl}"`.
 
Maybe you are interested in another way as in this example: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/graphic-name.html