# Bootstrap hamburger navbar icon is missing

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, hamburger-menu

I use bootstrap 4 to make the navbar, when I make my window smaller, the hamburger is there, but it won't show up. It's functional, but I can't see it. Can anyone help me with this?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-custom">
    <div class="container"><a href="#landing" class="navbar-brand">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav nav-fill w-100">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#landing">HOME</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#about">ABOUT</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#skill">SKILL</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#work">EXPERIENCE</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: please reformat or accept the current edit request that has been submitted to you

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap 4 has added new classes: navbar-dark and navbar-light, depending on your background color, you can add one of these classes to your navigation to make your mobile toggle visible.

You could also do something completely custom with a background color (shown below), or by swapping out the default icon.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
       <!-- Navbar content -->
    </nav>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary">
      <!-- Navbar content -->
    </nav>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-light" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;">
      <!-- Navbar content -->
    </nav>
```

AND if you really want to get fancy with animations and custom icons, check out these navbar customization examples:
[MDBootstrap examples](https://mdbootstrap.com/components/bootstrap-hamburger-menu/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I want my navbar background is transparent, but when the window is small, I want it has background color. Is that even possible?

Comment: It is Nicole, you can use media queries to accomplish this.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

OR
You can use javascript or jquery to create a "listener" to measure browser window width, and then add and remove css classes based on the width. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18477016/switching-css-classes-based-on-screen-size

Comment: Also take a look here to understand specificity and the Bootstrap mobile menu style: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20540563/change-icon-bar-color-in-bootstrap

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: black;
}

Comment: Hi, I think I know where the problem is... I always thought "☰" can only made by some complicated codes, but apparently I only need to add one line `<i class="fa fa-bars fa-1x"></i>`, and now it solved. As simple as that... But still thank you for your time. :)

Answer (score 0):

By default your toggler is transparent;

```
.navbar-toggler {
padding: .25rem .75rem;
font-size: 1.25rem;
line-height: 1;
background-color: transparent;
border: 1px solid transparent;
border-radius: .25rem;
```

}

Comment: Yes, I know I can modify here, but I don't know how to let the three little lines show up? (Can you understand what I meant? :P)

Comment: You can add that with 
'span class="navbar-toggler-icon"'

Comment: The full html code of my navbar is in my question. If you want to see the CSS, here it is.
`.navbar-custom {
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    .navbar-brand {
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    .navbar-custom .navbar-brand,
    .navbar-custom .navbar-text {
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
    }
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .nav-link {
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    }
    .navbar-custom .nav-item.active .nav-link,
    .navbar-custom .nav-item:hover .nav-link,
    .navbar-brand:hover {
        color: #6df0f5;
    } `

Comment: Most easy is when you take a look at this page: 

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/ 

Just start rebuilding, with the knowledge of the suggested color variations above. There will be a little mistake in the HTML. Also a important thing; just use the Bootstrap CSS from the CDN

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have any color scheme applied to the `nav` element. Without the theming classes the hamburger icon is transparent.

Adding `navbar-dark bg-dark` to your `nav` element would fix this problem.

[Color Schemes Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/#color-schemes)

Comment: I use custom theme because I want the navbar background is transparent. But I want it shows up when the window is smaller.