# CSS content attribute, what it means

Tags: css

wanted to put a social icons on my site, when looking for some i ran across this site:

[A site with a social icons that i want to adapt](http://kutoa.com/collections/apparel/products/kutoa-strapback)

[image]

then i saw that they are not images:

[image]

I don't know that css attribute "content"- what is it?

what is \e006, is it a font? looked at the site resources but didn't see anything related.

and looked for it on google "css content attribute" and "css \e006" But no luck.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content

Comment: it is the unicode name for a custom icon font. see [**http://fontello.com/**](http://fontello.com/)

Comment: @Chris M, are they free for commercial use?

Comment: there are many sites with both free icons and paid icons. read the eula

Comment: @Chris M, sorry but I don't understand. if they are icons. then how do i paint then in other color(like orange)in the site.. dont i need another colored icons set?

Comment: and really, don't understand why down voting. tried to be very clear, tried to searched for it.. and asked for something i don't know.

Comment: I agree. This was useful - I had the same question. Needs upvotes, not downvotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `::before` selector inserts content before the content of the selected class that is `.icon-instagram`. We use the `content` property to specify the content to insert. You can only use the `content` property with pseudo-elements like `:after` and `:before`.

In your case, `\e006` is a UTF-8 [character](http://www.utf8icons.com/character/57350/UTF-8-character). What happens is, whenever something has the class `.icon-instagram` applied to it, it will append this character before it. This is what it means by the pseudo-element `:before`. It might be a glyphicon. (Instagram icon).

Comment: Nice, and if i want to add an hover effect to it.. how can it "paint" the icon.. don't it need another set of colored icons?

Comment: The e006 is the Instagram icon. If you use the developer console and edit the CSS in the content, i.e. remove the char, the Instagram icon disappears. You want to paint what, the same icon again? Use the same code.

Comment: i mean like in the link i posted, when you hover them they are colored with orange

Comment: I see, okay, well that is another question, but I can tell you: Try utilizing the :hover, so create .icon-instagram:hover { } and add whatever you want it to look like upon the hover.

Comment: can you direct me to some question, tutorial on how to paint icons like that?

Comment: I think you can post a new question here on SO giving us directions of what is it that you are trying to achieve. Please close this question, +1 or mark as solve if it helped you understand "content and pseudo-elements" better. Thanks.

Comment: thanks, can you please write the question subject that i need to ask here? so i won't get any down vote:)

Comment: Here's a link that will surely help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379153/can-i-add-color-to-bootstrap-icons-only-using-css

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i have looked:)