# Jquery for change dropdown icon box after clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I create a click event but that event affects both dropdown i want do one by one, also i would like when I click in the next dropbox the first icon back to place, does not matter if i click in the first or second always puting back the icon that is my html and jquery : http://jsfiddle.net/rtu1tzep/

html:

```
    <div class="body-title">
        title
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-16">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg dropdown-toggle btn_body" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      <span id="users_label">users</span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
       <div class="col-md-16">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg dropdown-toggle btn_body" data-toggle="dropdown">
     <span id="clients_label">clients</span>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></i>

             </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

jquery:

```
  $( ".btn_body" ).click(function(){
    $('i').removeClass('glyphicon-asterisk');
    $('i').addClass('glyphicon-star');
  });
```

Comment: You are not working on the specific clicked icon, you are applying changes on the class selector. check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rtu1tzep/1/

Comment: looks perfect thank you, but how can I put back the icon if I click in other dropdown

Comment: check now change jquery

Comment: check my answer with color change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rtu1tzep/5/)

```
  $(".btn_body").click(function () {
      $(this).find('i').toggleClass('glyphicon-asterisk glyphicon-star');
      if ($(".btn_body").not(this).find("i").hasClass("glyphicon-star")) {
          $(".btn_body").not(this).find("i").toggleClass('glyphicon-asterisk glyphicon-star');
      }
  });
```

Comment: @Raduken we are here to help :).

Comment: how can i change the colour of the star? its possible too?

Comment: @Raduken that depends, how is the star coming? if from an image you have to change the image used in the css class

Comment: coming from a bootstrap class called: .glyphicon :)

Comment: then an image is used, most probably a sprite, check out this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379153/can-i-add-color-to-bootstrap-icons-only-using-css

Comment: check my answer with color change

Comment: @vinay , can we say for the class: glyphicon-star be white? changing the color attribute?, its just what i need :)

Comment: yes the stack over flow i mentioned states that in bootstrap 3, the icons are basically fonts, so you can change the color by using the Css color property. @LaljiTadhani has done the same in his answer.

Comment: nice thanks all, I updated the jsfiddle, but last question how can i change the color of the span element too? :) https://jsfiddle.net/rtu1tzep/7/

Answer (score 1):

Change your Jquery.

```
$(".btn_body").click(function () {
        $('.btn_body').find('i').addClass('glyphicon-asterisk');
        $('.btn_body').find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-star').css('color', '');
        $(this).find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-asterisk');
        $(this).find('i').addClass('glyphicon-star').css('color', 'red');
    });
```

Comment: Thanks very much, works well, but how can i put back the icon when i click in other dropdown?

Comment: check now change jquery

Comment: thanks a lot for the help, its working, i gave you some points

Comment: $(this).find('span').css('color', 'red');

Comment: very nice its works :), i just got a problem now, if i click on dropdown and after i click i another part of the page the icon still the same, how the icon can back to the original?

Comment: $('.btn_body').find('span').css('color', '');

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89056/discussion-between-raduken-and-lalji-tadhani).

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want I think.

```
$( ".btn_body" ).click(function(){
  $('i').removeClass('glyphicon-star');
  $('i').addClass('glyphicon-asterisk');
  $(this).children('i').removeClass('glyphicon-asterisk');
  $(this).children('i').addClass('glyphicon-star');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$( ".btn_body" ).click(function(){
$('i').removeClass('glyphicon-star');
$('i').addClass('glyphicon-asterisk');
$(this).children('i').removeClass('glyphicon-asterisk');
$(this).children('i').addClass('glyphicon-star');
});
```