# How can I make a Glyphicon with inverse coloring with React-Bootstrap?

Tags: glyphicons, react-bootstrap

Using React-Bootstrap, how can I make an inverse glyphicon button?

I have buttons like this:

```
    <Button onClick={this.onHome} >
    <Glyphicon glyph="home" /> 
    </Button>
```

but I'd like them to appear reversed.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379153/can-i-add-color-to-bootstrap-icons-only-using-css) asks about colors which is not the same.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To show a glyph on a green colored background, use `bsStyle="success"`:

```
<Button onClick={this.onHome} bsStyle="success">
  <Glyphicon glyph="home" /> 
</Button>
```

Another example, using a label instead of a button:

```
<Label bsStyle="success"><Glyphicon glyph="home" /></Label>
```

Some alternatives to `success` are `warning` `info` and for Button also `link`. The complete list is in the documentation at http://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html

Comment: Thanks, but I was asking how to reverse the colors of the buttons.  I thought it must be possible since the React-Bootstrap "Navbar" control has the "inverse" property which does this (for NavBar only).